# SQL in Oracle(LiveSQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

How to add multiple records at once using SQL in a table in Oracle Live SQL?

I have the used the statement in screenshot(as link) below but got an error-"ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

[image: Screenshot of the statements that I am using]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use `INSERT ALL`:

```
insert all
  into students (sr_no, name, class, sec, contact, total_marks) values (1, 'Ravi' , 10, 'A', 12345, 579)
  into students (sr_no, name, class, sec, contact, total_marks) values (2, 'Ria'  , 10, 'B', 98765, 580)
  into students (sr_no, name, class, sec, contact, total_marks) values (3, 'Aditi', 10, 'A', 98498, 570)
select * From dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use values in `select .. from dual union all` and use `INSERT INTO TABLE <t> SELECT ...` as follows:

```
insert into your_table
select val1,2,3,4,5 from dual union all
select val1,2,3,4,5 from dual union all
select val1,2,3,4,5 from dual union all
select val1,2,3,4,5 from dual
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3aba440dd48b2051441aeae317713792)

Comment: Can I do it without using queries?

Comment: Every database has its own way of doing the things. Why you don't want to use the query which is using the dual table.

Comment: What is "dual table"?

Comment: It is a dummy table provided by oracle having 1 column and 1 row. You must read about dual table as it is very useful in oracle